# Как в имени автора поста в WordPress вывести произвольную надпись?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

Очень хочу, чтобы в авторстве поста в WordPress выводилось не имя, а текст (имя сайта). Понимаю, что в настройках профиля есть возможность выбрать, что будет отображаться. Но проблема в том, что комментарии я тоже пишу с этого аккаунта и там необходим вывод обычного имени.

Я нашёл такой код:

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'guest_author_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'guest_author_name' );

function guest_author_name( $name ) {
global $post;

$author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'guest-author', true );

if ( $author )
$name = $author;

return $name;
}
```

Тут имя берётся из произвольного поля, но для меня это избыточно, мне необходимо задать фиксированное имя. Как будет выглядеть этот код с учётом данной модификации?

Comment: Зачем эти костыли? Что мешает исправить в теме?

Comment: В авторах всех статей выводить название твоего сайта, а в комментариях указывать стандартное имя?

Comment: SeVlad В теме можно, но не в сниппете для Google

Comment: Если авторизован в WordPress, то уже не укажешь имя. Может я просто не информирован и это реально сделать, но в опциях я этого не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой код:

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'guest_author_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'guest_author_name' );

function guest_author_name( $name ) {
    $name = get_bloginfo();

    return $name;
}
```